# Unexpected Massive Storage Usage

Tags: ios, ios7, realm

I have an application that allows users to post messages in a UITableView for other users to view. I am using Parse.com as the backend for my application.. All of the information displayed in the table is fetched from parse each time the table is loaded. The problem that I am having is that when the user scrolls through the posts in the table, the application begins sucking up memory from disk. The application begins at around 9MB, and after scrolling up and down through all the posts for a couple of minutes, can blow up to over 500MB.

I cannot imagine how this is happening, because I am not persisting any of the data to disk. Has anyone seen this before, or have any idea what might be sucking up so much storage? Or does anyone have a good strategy to figure out exactly what is being stored?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

So I have found the code that is sucking up all the memory. When I comment out the call to this method I do not experience the problem.

Here is the code:

Basically I am checking an internal database (using Realm.io) to see if the post was liked by the current user. The call to [Post objectsWithPredicate:pred] takes a LOT of memory. Why would it do this? Wouldn't the memory be freed as soon as the variable goes out of scope? Or is this due to some detail in Realm that has gone over my head?

```
    - (void)updateButtonColorForCell:(PostTableViewCell *)cell withPost:(PFObject *)post
{
    UIColor *themeColor = ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).themeColor;

    // Make all user-liked cells theme color with white text
    NSString *dappedPosts;
    if ([post.parseClassName isEqualToString:@"Message"]) {
        likedPosts = @"likedMessages";
    } else if ([post.parseClassName isEqualToString:@"Comment"]) {
        likedPosts = @"likedComments";
    }
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"objectId = %@", post.objectId];
    RLMArray *matches = [Post objectsWithPredicate:pred];
        if ([matches count]) {
            if (((Post *)[matches firstObject]).likedByMe) {
                cell.button.backgroundColor = themeColor;
                [cell.button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            } else {
                cell.button.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                [cell.button setTitleColor:themeColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Message not found in db");
        }
}
```

Comment: This is what Instruments is for. Use the Allocations tool of Instruments and see what is using all of the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed with the latest release which you can download here: http://static.realm.io/downloads/cocoa/latest

Answer (score 1):

Run your app in the simulator and watch the Application directory (~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/version/Applications/app-install-id/) to see what files are being written to. Before you can attempt to fix and disk space leaks, you need to know which files are being leaked into.